# Deployment to AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to automate the deployment of the AWS ECS and couldn't find much information I could do that and will like to see if there is any advice on what I can explore. Currently, we have an Azure DevOps pipeline that will push the containerized image to the ECR and we will manually create the task definition at ecs and update the service afterwards. Is there anyway that I can automate this with azure devops release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit open ended for a Stackoverflow style question but the short answer is that there are a lot of AWS native alternatives to this. [This is an example](https://ecsworkshop.com/blue_green_deployments/) that implements the blue-green pattern (it can be simplified with a more generic rolling update deployment). If you are new to ECS you probably want to consider using [Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/). [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/aws-copilot-an-application-first-cli-for-containers-on-aws/) is a entry level blog that hints about how to deploy an application and build a pipeline for it.